# How to implement Laravel pagination in bootstrap table using wenzhixin plugin

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-5

laravel pagination() returns the following data as a response but bootstrap table does not understand it. how can I solve this problem?

Route: Route::post('/student-statement', [StatementController::class, 'index']);
data-url="/student-statement"

```
    public function index(){
    $expenses = DB::table('students')
        ->join('statements', 'students.id', '=', 'student_id')
        ->select('student_id', 'students.name', 'tuition', 'graduation', 'other',
            DB::raw('format(tuition+graduation+other,0) as total,
            (students.payback/100)*(tuition+graduation+other) as payback'),
            'paid')->addSelect(DB::raw('(students.payback/100)(tuition+graduation+other)-paid as balance'))
        ->paginate(10);

    return response()->json($expenses);

}
```

Server responser:

```
current_page: 1
data: [,…]
first_page_url: "http://192.168.137.1:8000/student-statement?page=1"
from: 1
last_page: 5
last_page_url: "http://192.168.137.1:8000/student-statement?page=5"
links: [{url: null, label: "&laquo; Previous", active: false},…]
next_page_url: "http://192.168.137.1:8000/student-statement?page=2"
path: "http://192.168.137.1:8000/student-statement"
per_page: 10
prev_page_url: null
to: 10
total: 45
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with ajax like that. You should push response data

```
<main class="py-4">
    <table
        id="table"
        data-toggle="table"
        data-height="460"
        data-ajax="ajaxRequest"
        data-search="true"
        data-side-pagination="server"
        data-pagination="true">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">ID</th>
            <th data-field="address_text">Item Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</main>

<script>
    // your custom ajax request here
    function ajaxRequest(params) {
        var url = 'http://**.localhost/api/orders'
        $.get(url + '?' + $.param(params.data)).then(function (res) {
            params.success(res.data)
        })
    }
</script>
```